# createUserJob Run More Than One Command

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, jinja2, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am using [the Helm chart for Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) and creating a user using the `createUserJob` section:

```yaml
airflow:
  createUserJob:
    command: ~
    args:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - |-
        exec \
        airflow {{ semverCompare ">=2.0.0" .Values.airflowVersion | ternary "users create" "create_user" }} "$@"
      - --
      - "-r"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.role }}"
      - "-u"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.username }}"
      - "-e"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.email }}"
      - "-f"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.firstName }}"
      - "-l"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.lastName }}"
      - "-p"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.password }}"
```

However, if it exists, I would like to delete the user before creating it, but the following does not work:

```yaml
airflow:
  createUserJob:
    command: ~
    args:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - |-
        exec \
        airflow users delete --username admin ;
        airflow {{ semverCompare ">=2.0.0" .Values.airflowVersion | ternary "users create" "create_user" }} "$@"
      - --
      - "-r"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.role }}"
      - "-u"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.username }}"
      - "-e"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.email }}"
      - "-f"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.firstName }}"
      - "-l"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.lastName }}"
      - "-p"
      - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.password }}"
```

Is there a way to run more than one command here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the word `exec`.

The syntax you show here runs `bash -c 'command' args` as the main container command, where `args` is a list of arguments that are expanded inside the command as `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, and so on.  Inside the command string `"$@"` expands to those positional parameters starting at `$1`.  This is set up correctly.

Inside the command string, `exec` is a [special built-in utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20): `exec some_command` replaces the current shell with `some_command`, and in effect ends the current script.  In a container context this is useful for controlling which process is the main container process, but in this short-lived script it's not especially necessary.  In particular if you're going to `exec` a command it must be the *last* command.

I might structure this as:

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |-
    airflow users delete --username "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.username }}";
    airflow users create "$@"
  # (no `exec` in this command string)
  - --
args:
  - "-r"
  - "{{ .Values.webserver.defaultUser.role }}"
  - "-et"
  - cetera
```

Here the `command:`/`args:` split is kind of artificial but it makes it slightly clearer how the command words are split up.

Comment: This worked for me as well on Airflow v2.3.0